# what is this notation for this graph edge weight?

Tags: graph-theory, notation

I'm new to graph theory and saw this notation for graph with data vectors.

Data vector $\{a_i\}^n_{i=1}$ and link weight $\{w_{ij}\}_{(i,j)\in{I_n}}$ where $I_n:=\{(i,j)\in \mathbb{N}^2|1≤i<j≤n\}$

So in this notation, if $n=200$, then does this graph have 200 nodes with 19900 weighted edges?

And I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, so can someone tell me if this is correct or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\binom{200}{2}=  \frac{200(199)}{2}=19900$$.

Yes, it's a graph with $n$ nodes and $\binom{n}{2}$ weighted edges.